# Expressjs: Connect public webserver (on a vserver) with local raspberry pi

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, webhooks

I want to make something happen on the raspberry pi when a webhook under my domain gets called (GET, POST etc.). This should be made possible by using javascript in nodejs.

What would be the best way to connect both servers.
Thx for advices!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your webhook has the following url: `https://example.com/webhook`.

Because a **webhook** is nothing more than an API being called, you can handle the route in Express like this:

```
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {

    // ... do your stuff here

    res.send('Webhook executed.');
});
```

You may replace `post` with whatever method you'd like to use.

Comment: But how can I let this working when my raspi isn't connected with the domain in any way. the raspi is running local.

Comment: @corusm Ah okay, I overread that. You have to setup a service like NoIP, because your PI has to be accessible from the internet to make that work what you are intending to do.